# Derivation of scattering coefficient as a function of number density of scatterers

Tags: scattering, intensity

I'm trying to derive the usual formula for intensity of light passing through scattering medium:

$$I=I_0\exp(-\alpha x),$$

where $\alpha$ is the scattering coefficient (assuming it's constant), and $x$ is the distance traveled by light in the medium. My objective is to define $\alpha$ as a function of number density of scatterers and total scattering cross-section of a single scatterer.

I start by considering a volume $V=Sx,$ where $S$ is cross-section of the volume perpendicular to direction $\vec x$ of propagation, and $x$ is its length in the direction of propagation. For a single scatterer with total scattering cross-section $\sigma$, probability of a ray hitting it is

$$P(\text{hit one})=\frac\sigma S.$$

Probability of missing $N$ scatterers in a row is thus

$$P(\text{miss }N)=\left(1-\frac\sigma S\right)^N.$$

Now I go from number of scatterers $N$ to number density $\nu$. It should satisfy

$$N=\nu{Sx}.$$

With this definition, probability of light ray passing through the length $x$ of the medium unscattered is

$$P(\text{pass length }x)=\left(1-\frac\sigma{S}\right)^{\nu Sx}.$$

Now, the $S$ parameter seems somehow extraneous. On the one hand, if I take the limit of $S\to\infty$, I get

$$\lim_{S\to\infty}P_{\text{pass}}(x)=\exp(-\sigma\nu x),$$

which looks convincing as a result (so that scattering coefficient $\alpha=\sigma\nu$). On the other hand, I can't seem to make much sense of this limit (which I tried evaluating just to see what I'd get, without justification).

I suppose I'm trying to apply some assumption which I haven't realized. Is this limit simply the thermodynamic limit, where we pretend to work with infinitely many particles? Or is this step simply wrong?